# COUNTIF in Google Sheets that checks 'if' a string is in one column before counting in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to use the COUNTIF function in Google Sheets.

**The Goal**

I want the 'dashboard' sheet to display the count of items in column F submitted to the responses sheet 'if' a specific string exists in column D.

Basically, I'm trying to count items in one column 'if' a control item exists in another column.

**I'm using this formula**

```
=COUNTIF(responses!D:D, "=A6", responses!F:F)
```

**What I've done**

In the example, I'm trying to check column D in the responses sheet for a string in cell A6 of the dashboard sheet. If the string exists in the column D of the responses sheet, then I want a count of the items in column F. I expect 0 to be returned for the NJROTC item.

**Request**

Can someone please review my formula and let me know what I'm doing wrong OR if there is a better solution than the COUNTIF function?

**Video Explaining the Problem**

http://youtu.be/J_ados6Ksq4

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this to solve my problem.

```
=IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP($A6,responses!$D:$M,3, FALSE)),"Yes","No")
```